# Row counts of a list tables in different databases

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of tables across multiple databases, and I would like to find out the row counts for these tables and the name of these tables.

Note that the names of the tables may change, as I need to repeat this many times, so ideally, I would like to specify the tables and then query some of the data dictionary tables.

I am able to achieve what I want, by writing multiple queries for each database and then sticking the results into one final table, but wondered if there is a solution that is more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example that will get the row counts for all tables in the specified databases in a single resultset. Add additional filters as appropriate for your needs.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = 
STUFF((SELECT N'UNION ALL SELECT
       N''' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'''
     + N''.'' 
     + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id, ' + CAST(d.database_id AS nvarchar(10)) + N'))
     + N''.''
     + QUOTENAME(t.name) AS TableName
     , SUM(p.rows) AS Rows
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.sys.tables AS t
JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.sys.partitions AS p ON p.object_id = t.object_id AND p.index_id IN(0,1)
GROUP BY       N''' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'''
     + N''.'' 
     + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id, ' + CAST(d.database_id AS nvarchar(10)) + N'))
     + N''.''
     + QUOTENAME(t.name)'
FROM sys.databases AS d
WHERE d.name IN(N'Database1', N'Database2)
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,10,'');

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am new to SQL, so can you please tell me what this code doea? I understand the core of the code, but you use QUOTENAME and XML PATH, and I am unfamiliar with them.

Comment: @Steve, the XML path is a string concatenation technique (detailed [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax/207380#207380)) to concatenate the queries for each database into a single `UNION ALL` query. The `QUOTENAME` function encloses the value in square brackets, needed if you were to have database or object names that don't conform the the [rules for regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of rows using system tables as well. If you need other tables from different databases as well, you can just use union and Change Adventure works to your DB name.

```
select t.name as Tablename, s.name  Schemaname  ,p.rows as Numberofrows  from AdventureWorks.sys.tables t 
join AdventureWorks.sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id 
join AdventureWorks.sys.indexes i on i.object_id = t.object_id 
join AdventureWorks.sys.partitions p on p.object_id = i.object_id and p.index_id = i.index_id 
group by t.name , s.name   ,p.rows
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I was wondering if this can be done in one query, as i don't want to repeat the query if I can help it